# Getting a NullReferenceException with Mono C# when using Gtk library TreeViewColumn

Tags: c#, mono, treeview

I am trying to display a sqlite database in a Gtk# TreeView, but when i append the columns into the treeview, a NullReferenceException occurs.

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using libraryGueyWrapper;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   

    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Tree ();
        Build ();
    }

    public void Tree ()
    {
        //Create the name column
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn name = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
        name.Title = "Name";

        table.AppendColumn (name); //Exception occurs on this line
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MainWindow.Tree () [0x00019] in /home/ayush/databaseManagementSystem/libraryGueyWrapper/libraryGueyWrapper/MainWindow.cs:20
  at MainWindow..ctor () [0x00009] in /home/ayush/databaseManagementSystem/libraryGueyWrapper/libraryGueyWrapper/MainWindow.cs:10
  at libraryGueyWrapper.TreeView.Main () [0x00006] in /home/ayush/databaseManagementSystem/libraryGueyWrapper/libraryGueyWrapper/Program.cs:11
```

I am very new to Mono and c#, and this is probably a simple mistake but i can't figure out what it is.

Note : I read [this link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6859/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) and it didn't really help. Also, i googled and found links to catch NullReferenceException, but what i want to do is fix it.

Comment: What is `table`? Did you try to debug where it throws NRE?

Comment: table is a Gtk.TreeView object. I created that using the designer, so it's not in the code. And yes, the NRE throws on table.AppendColumn (name); I put a comment beside it in the code

Comment: Try to call `Tree()` after `Build()`

Comment: Yup! that worked. but i still don't know why it worked.

Comment: I think `Build()` in Gtk is equals to `InitializeComponent()` in WinForms, Wpf. It is method which creates controls you added in designer. So before call this method these controls are not exist.